# Сортировка по дате в mysql - месяцы выводятся в обратном порядке.

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.
При сортировка по дате сортировка происходит по числам, но месяцы выводятся в обратном порядке - ноябрь, октябрь.
Вот запрос:

> ```
> SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,  '%d %M %Y') AS `date` FROM
> ```
>
> `table` WHERE
> `start`='$search' AND `end` =
> '$search1' AND `date` BETWEEN
> curdate() AND curdate() + interval 2
> month ORDER BY date  DESC"

Что поправить, чтобы выводилось все правильно - дни и месяцы по возрастанию?

Comment: при ASC вместо DESC выводятся месяцы наизнанку.

Comment: Я так понимаю DATE_FORMAT возвращает строку? Тогда у Вас и получается сортировка не по полю даты table.date, а по строковому плю DATE_FORMAT(date,  '%d %M %Y') с алиасом `date

Comment: Как же быть? DATE_FORMAT используется для приведения даты к нормальному для чтения виду. Как тогда произвести сортировку?

Answer (score 2):

DESC - сортировка от большего к меньшему.
ASC - от меньшего к большему.

Comment: Это понятно, при ASC числа сортируются нормально, а вот месяцы наоборот. Получается сначала идет 2 ноября, потом 5 октября. А надо наоборот.

Comment: SELECT *, date AS `sortdate`, DATE_FORMAT(date,  '%d %M %Y') AS `date` FROM
table WHERE start='$search' AND end = '$search1' AND sortdate BETWEEN curdate() AND curdate() + interval 2 month ORDER BY sortdate DESC"

Comment: Не работает, вообще ничего не выводит. Объясните для чего вводиться sortdate?

Comment: Чтобы сортировка была не по дате, приведенной к строковому виду, а по дате, в формате datetime. Тогда сортирока будет правильной. У тебя один из alias называется date, поэтому реальному полю date пришлось дать alias sortdate. Проверь еще раз переменные, на вид должно работать.

Answer (score 2):

В данном примере я бы сделал так в конце:

`ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')) DESC`

Отмечу - `%Y-%m-%d` именно в таком порядке в базе данных расположены части даты.

И да, будет вроде проще так. И еще - `date` вроде зарезервированное слово в `MySql`.